# What do you pass to a method wait(int*)

Tags: iphone, ios, c

When I simply pass the int I get the warning:

> WARNING: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing int to parameter of
>   type int *

In another words what is `int *`

Comment: `int *` expects _address of int_ and not _int_

Comment: @VoidPointer can you post an example? Should it be `int i = 1, wait(&i);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This requires the *address* of an integer variable, not the integer variable itself. You can get the address of a variable with the `&` operator. So the following code would work:

```
int i = 10;
wait( &i );
```

Answer (score 7):

The man page for [`wait()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man2/wait.2.html) describes what the argument is for:

> `pid_t`
>    `wait(int *stat_loc);`
>
> The `wait()` function suspends execution of its calling process until `stat_loc` information is available for a terminated child process, or a signal is received.  On return from a successful `wait()` call, the `stat_loc` area contains termination information about the process that exited as defined below.

The `*` indicates that a pointer is desired. Since arguments are passed by value to function calls, the way a value is returned via a function parameter is through a pointer to the object receiving the value.

```
int status;
pid_t p;

p = wait(&status);
```